# Convert BooleanRegion to a Polygon

Tags: regions, polygons

I have two very simple polygons.

```
a = Polygon[{{2, 0}, {2, 100}, {502, 100}, {502, 0}, {2, 0}}]
b = Polygon[{{202, -200}, {202, 296}, {300, 296}, {300, -200}, {202, -200}}]
```

> [image]

I wish to produce a new polygon which (for example) describes their union as pictured above, but is expressed as a single `Polygon[]` instance. In this simple case, I can create it by-hand as:

```
c = Polygon[{
    {2, 0}, {2, 100}, {202, 100}, {202, 296}, {300, 296}, 
    {300, 100}, {502, 100}, {502, 0}, {300, 0}, {300, -200}, 
    {202, -200}, {202, 0}, {2, 0}}}]
```

Of course, I wish to obtain this polygon automatically.
Unfortunately `RegionUnion` above returns a `BooleanRegion`:

> [image]

This is despite some other region functions like `RegionIntersection` returning a `Polygon`.

> [image]

In fact, I have difficulty predicting what families of polygons will return `Polygon` (or other acceptable symbols like `Triangle`) vs `BooleanRegion` when given to functions `RegionIntersection`, `RegionUnion`, `RegionDifference`.

How can I convert a `BooleanRegion` of two simple `Polygon`s into a `Polygon` (or a list thereof)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could discretize the polygons, which lets the union operation return the object as a `BoundaryMeshRegion`. From there you can extract the polygons as long as there are no holes.

```
MeshPrimitives[RegionUnion @@ BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics /@ {a, b}, 2]
```

> ```
> {Polygon[{{202., 100.}, {2., 100.}, {2., 0.}, {202., 0.}, 
>  {202., -200.}, {300., -200.}, {300., 0.}, {502., 0.}, {502., 100.},
>  {300., 100.}, {300., 296.}, {202., 296.}}]}
> ```