# Unify Polyhedrons into a single Polyhedron

Tags: regions, geometry, mesh, 3d-printing, polyhedra

Consider these two simple Polyhedrons which share a sub-face:

```
p1 = Polyhedron[
    {{0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 1}, {2, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}},
    {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {4, 1, 5, 8}}];

p2 =  TransformedRegion[p1, TranslationTransform[{1, 0, 1}]];
```

> [image]

I wish to produce a third Polyhedron which describes the union of these shapes, as suggested by the `Region` admitted by `RegionUnion`:

> [image]

Unfortunately the Polyhedron produced by `RegionUnion` has not merged the 'side faces' but has actually split up previous individual faces!

> [image]

It seems like `MeshCells[]` is unable to return a single Polyhedron describing the full volume.

```
MeshCells[RegionUnion[p1, p2], 3]

>>> MeshCells: There is no simple cell representation for the specified cells of the BoundaryMeshRegion
```

My issues with the generated polyhedron do not appear to constitute mesh defects:

> [image]

In principle, I can obtain a list of all the individual faces admitted by `RegionUnion`...

```
p3 = RegionUnion[p1, p2];
coords = First[p3];
faces = MeshCells[p3, 2] /. i_Integer :> coords[[i]];
```

and attempt to stitch them myself into "clean" polyhedron faces by unifying co-planar edge-intersecting faces (using e.g. `Not @ RegionDisjoint[faces[[i]], faces[[j]]`). This appears to require rotating co-planar faces into 2D Polygon, merging them and rotating back - quite a pain for one might expect as a basic Mathematica function!

Is there a way to achieve a simple unified Polyhedron like the one I have constructed below by hand:

```
p3 = Polyhedron[{
    {0, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 2}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1},
    {0, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 1}, {3, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}
}, {
    Range[8], 8 + Range[8],
    {1, 8,  16 , 9},
    Sequence @@ Table[i + {0, 1, 9, 8}, {i, 7}]
}]
```

[image]

## Adverserial example for cvgmt's solution

The proposed solution of

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ RegionUnion[{p1,p2}] // Region`Mesh`MergeCells
```

has some issues for longer lists of more complicated Polyhedron.

For example:

```
vols = {Polyhedron[{{202., 277.22222222222223`, 40}, {300., 250., 
      40}, {300., 296., 40}, {202., 296., 40}, {202., 
      277.22222222222223`, 52}, {300., 250., 52}, {300., 296., 
      52}, {202., 296., 52}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 6, 
    5}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {4, 1, 5, 8}}], 
   Polyhedron[{{400., 257.77777777777777`, 40}, {400., 
      222.22222222222223`, 40}, {480., 200., 40}, {400., 
      257.77777777777777`, 52}, {400., 222.22222222222223`, 
      52}, {480., 200., 52}}, {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {1, 2, 5, 4}, {2,
      3, 6, 5}, {3, 1, 4, 6}}], 
   Polyhedron[{{400., 257.77777777777777`, 0}, {300., 330., 0}, {150.,
       350., 0}, {120., 300., 0}, {202., 277.22222222222223`, 
      0}, {202., 296., 0}, {300., 296., 0}, {300., 250., 0}, {400., 
      222.22222222222223`, 0}, {400., 257.77777777777777`, 12}, {300.,
       330., 12}, {150., 350., 12}, {120., 300., 12}, {202., 
      277.22222222222223`, 12}, {202., 296., 12}, {300., 296., 
      12}, {300., 250., 12}, {400., 222.22222222222223`, 12}}, {{1, 2,
      3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}, {1, 
     2, 11, 10}, {2, 3, 12, 11}, {3, 4, 13, 12}, {4, 5, 14, 13}, {5, 
     6, 15, 14}, {6, 7, 16, 15}, {7, 8, 17, 16}, {8, 9, 18, 17}, {9, 
     1, 10, 18}}], 
   Polyhedron[{{312., 246.66667169012294`, 12}, {312., 308., 
      12}, {190., 308., 12}, {190., 280.55554604499355`, 12}, {202., 
      277.22222222222223`, 12}, {202., 296., 12}, {300., 296., 
      12}, {300., 250., 12}, {312., 246.66667169012294`, 52}, {312., 
      308., 52}, {190., 308., 52}, {190., 280.55554604499355`, 
      52}, {202., 277.22222222222223`, 52}, {202., 296., 52}, {300., 
      296., 52}, {300., 250., 52}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10,
      11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}, {1, 2, 10, 9}, {2, 3, 11, 10}, {3, 4, 
     12, 11}, {4, 5, 13, 12}, {5, 6, 14, 13}, {6, 7, 15, 14}, {7, 8, 
     16, 15}, {8, 1, 9, 16}}], 
   Polyhedron[{{388., 266.444472098731, 12}, {388., 
      225.55554579605914`, 12}, {400., 222.22222222222223`, 
      12}, {400., 257.77777777777777`, 12}, {388., 266.444472098731, 
      52}, {388., 225.55554579605914`, 52}, {400., 
      222.22222222222223`, 52}, {400., 257.77777777777777`, 52}}, {{1,
     2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 
    7}, {4, 1, 5, 8}}]};
```

> [image]

```
(* doesn't evaluate *)
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion @ RegionUnion[vols]

>>> BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[BooleanRegion[#1 || #2 || #3 || #4 || #5 &, {vols}]]


% // Region`Mesh`MergeCells

>>> Region`Mesh`MergeCells[ BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[ ... ] ]
```

We could discretise *first* to avoid `BooleanRegion` as per [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275205/convert-booleanregion-to-a-polygon)...

```
(* evaluates to a BoundaryMeshRegion *)
reg = RegionUnion[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ testvols]
```

> [image]

Alas, now calling `MergeCells[reg]` throws an error:

```
>>> BoundaryMeshRegion::bsuncl: The boundary surface is not closed because the edges Line[{{34,36},{37,35},{36,37},{35,34}}] only come from a single face.
```

It is also not clear to me how to extract a `Polyhedron` from the resulting `BoundaryMeshRegion` when this technique *does* work.

## Another strange adverserial example

Consider the list of polyhedrons:

```
vols = {InputForm[
Polyhedron[{{300., 164.53571428571428`, 10}, {202., 
      163.36904761904762`, 10}, {202., -44.66666666666667, 
      10}, {249., -76., 10}, {300., -44.125, 10}, {300., 
      164.53571428571428`, 20}, {202., 163.36904761904762`, 
      20}, {202., -44.66666666666667, 20}, {249., -76., 
      20}, {300., -44.125, 20}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {
     1, 2, 7, 6}, {2, 3, 8, 7}, {3, 4, 9, 8}, {4, 5, 10, 9}, {5, 1, 6,
      10}}]], InputForm[
Polyhedron[{{300., -44.125, 0}, {249., -76., 
      0}, {202., -44.66666666666667, 0}, {202., -200., 
      0}, {300., -200., 0}, {300., -44.125, 10}, {249., -76., 
      10}, {202., -44.66666666666667, 10}, {202., -200., 
      10}, {300., -200., 10}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1,
      2, 7, 6}, {2, 3, 8, 7}, {3, 4, 9, 8}, {4, 5, 10, 9}, {5, 1, 6, 
     10}}]], InputForm[
Polyhedron[{{202., 296., 0}, {202., 163.36904761904762`, 0}, {300., 
      164.53571428571428`, 0}, {300., 296., 0}, {202., 296., 
      10}, {202., 163.36904761904762`, 10}, {300., 
      164.53571428571428`, 10}, {300., 296., 10}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 
    6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {4, 1, 5, 
    8}}]], InputForm[
Polyhedron[{{300.00000220959214`, -55.91747503407568, 
      10}, {300., -44.125, 10}, {249., -76., 
      10}, {202., -44.66666666666667, 
      10}, {202.00000237873843`, -56.68517250403892, 
      10}, {248.82501070724447`, -87.90184472304296, 
      10}, {300.00000220959214`, -55.91747503407568, 
      20}, {300., -44.125, 20}, {249., -76., 
      20}, {202., -44.66666666666667, 
      20}, {202.00000237873843`, -56.68517250403892, 
      20}, {248.82501070724447`, -87.90184472304296, 20}}, {{1, 2, 3, 
     4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}, {1, 2, 8, 7}, {2, 3, 9, 8}, {3, 
     4, 10, 9}, {4, 5, 11, 10}, {5, 6, 12, 11}, {6, 1, 7, 12}}]], 
  InputForm[
Polyhedron[{{300., 174.5364228773892, 10}, {202., 173.36975621072256`,
       10}, {202., 163.36904761904762`, 10}, {300., 
      164.53571428571428`, 10}, {300., 174.5364228773892, 20}, {202., 
      173.36975621072256`, 20}, {202., 163.36904761904762`, 
      20}, {300., 164.53571428571428`, 20}}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 
    8}, {1, 2, 6, 5}, {2, 3, 7, 6}, {3, 4, 8, 7}, {4, 1, 5, 8}}]]}
```

Attempting to merge these volumes by the same technique above makes two of the faces (and the bounded volume in-between) disappear!

[image]

Comment: I have provide three methods,but you still down vote my answer. So I will never answer all of your question!

Comment: Three methods with no explanatory text, which didn't work for my examples, and which didn't address my request for obtaining a *Polyhedron*. I hardly think you got to 43k rep doing *that*

Comment: What is the reason that you want a single polyhedron?

Comment: @user21 the final single Polyhedron is exported to use in other software

Comment: @cvgmt I *have* your original answer, and it made no mention of returning `Polyhedron`. What's your game here?

Comment: If it is possible to work with the faces of the polygon rather than the polyhedron one could merge polygons that are coplanar using [CoplanarPoints](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoplanarPoints.html) in version 13. That could be done by making a list of faces and using `Gather` with `CoplanarPoints` and maybe applying `RegionUnion` on each group of faces. There are also answers on stack exchange for grouping coplanar faces.

Answer (score 4):

This is a comment not an answer. This should be more robust:

```
Needs["OpenCascadeLink`"]
r = RegionUnion @@ vols;
shape = OpenCascadeShape[r];
bmesh = OpenCascadeShapeSurfaceMeshToBoundaryMesh[shape];
mr = MeshRegion[bmesh];
Region`Mesh`MergeCells[mr]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did not read all the details of the question but I noticed that taking the complement of the complement of the union of the polygons reduces the number of faces and so it might be what you are looking for:

```
poly = RegionUnion[p1, p2];
```

Number of faces : 18 (seen in the Polyhedron box image)

```
boundr = RegionUnion[p1, p2] // BoundingRegion;
RegionDifference[boundr, RegionDifference[boundr, poly]];
```

Number of faces : 16

Comment: `BoundingRegion` doesn't work on `RegionUnion[vols]` since the latter is a `BooleanRegion`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this may be useful.

extrude is a function I wrote to avoid a problem in RegionProduct. I have reported that issue to Wolfram support already. The problem appears as beveled corners and edges.

First the images and then the code:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[None], 
   polygon1 = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {2, 1}], 
   polygon2 = Translate[polygon1, {1, 1}]}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
  
MeshRegion[polygon1]

MeshRegion[polygon2]

shape = First[MeshPrimitives[CanonicalizeRegion[
     RegionUnion[MeshRegion[polygon1], MeshRegion[polygon2]]], 
    2]]
    
extrude = Function[{interval, polygon}, 
    Block[{span, canonical, bottom, top, edges, i, j, k, 
      points, faces}, span = Sort[interval]; 
      canonical = CanonicalizePolygon[polygon]; 
      points = Union[Sort[Join[(Append[#1, span[[1,1]]] & ) /@ 
           canonical[[1]], (Append[#1, span[[1,2]]] & ) /@ 
           canonical[[1]]]]]; bottom = 
       (Append[canonical[[1,#1]], span[[1,1]]] & ) /@ 
        Reverse[canonical[[2]]]; bottom = 
       First[Flatten[(Position[points, #1] & ) /@ bottom, 
         {2, 3}]]; top = (Append[canonical[[1,#1]], 
          span[[1,2]]] & ) /@ canonical[[2]]; 
      top = First[Flatten[(Position[points, #1] & ) /@ top, 
         {2, 3}]]; edges = Table[j = top[[i]]; 
         k = top[[Mod[i + 1, Length[top], 1]]]; 
         {j - 1, k - 1, k, j}, {i, Length[top]}]; 
      faces = Join[{bottom, top}, edges]; 
      CanonicalizePolyhedron[Polyhedron @@ {points, faces}]]]; 
      
InputForm[Rationalize[shape]]

Region[extrude[Interval[{0, 1}], shape]]

Region[RegionProduct[Interval[{0, 1}], shape]]
```

```
Wed 22 Mar 2023 19:49:53GMT-4
13.2.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)
Microsoft Windows 10 Pro  10.0.19045  
{DisplayVersion,22H2}
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz  
{NumberOfCores,8}
{Capacity     DeviceLocator   PartNumber        Speed,
 17179869184  ChannelA-DIMM0  F4-3200C16-16GVK  3200,
 17179869184  ChannelA-DIMM1  F4-3200C16-16GVK  3200,
 17179869184  ChannelB-DIMM0  F4-3200C16-16GVK  3200,
 17179869184  ChannelB-DIMM1  F4-3200C16-16GVK  3200}
```

Of course, I may have missed something.

Comment: You can use OpenCascadeLink to extrude, no need to write a function.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I had "extrude" already on hand; it was written several months again and long before I heard of OpenCascadeLink. And, this way "the how it was done" is visible.